# how to add user defined appearance icons using annotation on signed pdf in itext? or Is it possible?

Tags: java, pdf, annotations, itext

I am trying to add "user defined appearance icons" on signed pdf.
How to implement issue?
Please help me to FIX it. Thanks.

Comment: What are *user defined appearance icons*? That term does not appear in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: Comment,Key,Help,NewParagraph,Insert etc as  for "key" adobe reader show key icon.

Comment: All I can infer from your comment is that it seems to have something to do with the Adobe Reader software. As the Adobe Reader here shows localized menu entries, I can't find where the other buzz words from your comment are meant to point at. Thus please explain your requirements, e.g. by a sample PDF showing what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Creating annotation with predefined icons is easy. Just look up "Annotation > annotation icons" in the [keywords list](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php): http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=294

Adding those annotations to a signed PDF is the tricky part. In some cases, this is impossible without breaking the signature, more specifically when the MDP settings of the signature prevent adding annotations. In that case your question is unanswerable.

However, if the MDP settings allow adding annotations, then you need to add the annotation using `PdfStamper` in append mode. Search the manual on [PDF and digital signatures](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) for the keywords "append mode".

```
public void addAnnotation(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper =
        new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest), '\0', true);
    PdfAnnotation comment = PdfAnnotation.createText(stamper.getWriter(),
       new Rectangle(200, 800, 250, 820), "Finally Signed!",
       "Bruno Specimen has finally signed the document", true, "Comment");
    stamper.addAnnotation(comment, 1);
    stamper.close();
}
```

Possible alternative values for "Comment" are "Key", "Note", "Help", "NewParagraph", "Paragraph", and "Insert".

Comment: But Bruno sir, in your documentaion i got this code snippet, but in this  am getting "Comment" icon.  my need is instead of "Comment" icon i want to show my own ".png" icon.

Comment: You can add annotations with appearances you define yourself, but as far as I understand ISO-32000-1, I don't think what you're asking is possible. Please follow mkl's advice and be more specific. It would help if you used the terminology used in the ISO standard (that's what standards are for, you know).

Comment: The links provided for http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=294 and    http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php both point to nowhere because the website was completely redone. A search on the new itext website or in the knowledge base for 'appearance icon' or 'keyword list' yields no useful results. Where is the iText documentation for function PdfAnnotation.createText that explains the valid values for parameter icon of type string ? @BrunoLowagie was kind enough to provide a list of alternative values here, but for those that want to look deeper under the hood it would be useful